# d3 svg rect height becomes NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am unable to debug the reason why the rect height becomes NaN , with the embedded code below.

Instead , if I just have .attr("height",yScale.bandwidth()) , then I would see proper height in HTML elements.

The csv file is loaded properly , as I'm able to access the country and year properly.

If needed , I can upload the full code.

```js
var rHeight       = function(d) { return d.ratio;};

//// data is of CSV format :
//country,ratio,year
//United States,0.33,1924
//United States,0.33,1928
//United States,0.33,1932
//United States,0.0,1936
//United States,0.17,1948
//United States,0.2,1952
//::
//::
//

        
        
        
        // draw rectangles
        svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(rpc_data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class","bar")
            .attr("x",xMap)
            .attr("y",yMap)
            .attr("width",xScale.bandwidth())
            .attr("height",Math.floor((yScale.bandwidth())*rHeight) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can see from your snippet `rHeight` it is a function, so when you run:

```
Math.floor((yScale.bandwidth())*rHeight
```

it is the same as `number * function` and you get `NaN` as result (check demo).

```js
console.log(1 * function() {});
```

You should calculate the height this way:

```
...
.attr("height", function(d){
  return Math.floor((yScale.bandwidth()) * rHeight(d)
}));
```